# PHP strlen - appending numbers based on string length

Tags: php

I am trying to append random numbers to different numbers of characters.  Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

```
$userName = $_SESSION['username'];
if(strlen($userName == 3)){
    $userName = $userName . rand(000,999);
}
else if (strlen($userName == 4)){
    $userName = $userName . rand(00,99);
}
else if (strlen($userName == 5)){
    $userName = $userName . rand(0,9);
}
echo "<br>" . $userName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
if(strlen($userName == 3))
```

To:

```
if(strlen($userName) == 3)
```

And repeat that correction for the other 2 conditions.

That will solve your syntax errors, but I would solve this problem a different way:

```
while (strlen($userName) < 6)
{
  $userName .= rand(0,9);
}
```

Comment: embarassing - did not see that. =)

Comment: Sometimes little syntax mistakes like that are almost impossible to see. I once spent an entire afternoon debugging my code before I finally realised I had a semicolon right after my `if`.

Comment: @user547794 See my edits. I propose a better method for you :)

Answer (score 1):

`000` is still `0`. Instead, use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) to explicity specify how many zeros you want.

```
$missingLen = 6 - strlen($username);

if($missingLen > 0) {
  $username = sprintf('%s%0'.$missingLen.'d', $username, rand(0, pow(10, $missingLen) - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what did not work: try to explicitly cast the number to a string:

```
$userName .= (string)rand(0, 999);
```